# Tizen sample code not running

Tags: android, eclipse, configuration, tizen

I've recently downloaded the Tizen SDK and I'm now trying to run a sample code (the sample Calculator project) just to see if everything works.
Well, it doesn't and I don't understand why.

Here's my problem: I have an emulator (which is launched, no problem so far) but when I run the project, I've got errors (missing .h files). But I haven't modified the project at all, what am I doing wrong?

I can't post an image so I'm just gonna copy the error message:

```
"Errors (3 items)

fatal error: 'view/main-view.h' file not found

make: ***[src/view/main-view.o] Error 1

recipe for target 'src/view/main-view.o' failed"
```

I've got Windows x64, and I'm trying to run this code (should I run the project instead ? How ?) with Tizen IDE.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... I've fixed it. Turns out I changed the location of my project when I created it (instead of using default workspace location), works fine if I keep the default location. Go figure...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, that the files view/main-view.h exist in project and in Project->Properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols in Source Location tab there is inc directory entry. And in main-app.c there is the include looks like that (without src path)

```
#include "view/main-view.h"
```

If this won't help make sure you are using the most recent SDK (they still have a lot of bugs). Maybe it is fixed. For me (Linux version) works, however it has two files only (one .h and one .cpp).

When I copied example from this site https://developer.tizen.org/downloads/sample-applications/sample-mobile-applications and I replaced my current workspace/proj content (removed current .c /.h files) it works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :D     Well the .h files are not present but I thought it was normal since sample code is supposed to work... I downloaded the SDK yesterday so I'm confident it's the latest version. I didn't understand the last part of your answer though, about the workspace replacement. I'm using Tizen 2.3 Rev2 SDK version.

Comment: Try add to the project missing files from given link. Last part of my answer means I replaced my projects files with these from example on given site.